# Amazon EC2 open ports for security groups present in other accounts

Tags: amazon-ec2

Assume, I am having 2 ec2 accounts (say A and B), both have different list of security groups. Now I want to open a particular port (say 80) for an instance running in account A, to account B. ie, I want to only allow account B instances, to access account A's 80 port. Could any one update me, is there a way to do this.??

Additionally, may I access account A's instance from account B's instance by using its private ip address/host name ??

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily achievable in the command line... and making use of the ec2 tools. Its not available within the AWS management console.

ec2-authorize --help

./ec2-authorize [AWS security group that the firewall hole will be poked into] -K [AWS pk-*.pem of the account where the firewall hole is to be made] -C [AWS cert*.pem of the account where the firewall hole is to be made] --region=[region] -P tcp -o [security group name of AWS account you want to allow access to] -u [account ID number - of the AWS account which you want to allow access to] -p [port number range. or single port numnber]

And that's it.
Look at AWS doc's for more information on ec2 tools to install etc if you don't know what they are.

Thats all you need,
Cheers

Comment: thanks for your info.. just a confirmation, whether the [AWS security group that the firewall hole will be poked into] can be of different account .. am I correct..??

Comment: thanks for your informations. I can open particular port to other accounts  by using your steps

thanks..

Comment: rahul, since the answer was correct, please mark it as correct.